# Installing Auto-Sklearn on Windows gives error

Tags: python, anaconda

There are many topics in Stackoverflow on AutoSklearn errors.

but each error is different and each environment is different

I have windows 10 64-bit

I installed Anaconda3

When I try to follow these steps

https://automl.github.io/auto-sklearn/stable/installation.html

Step 1 :

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/automl/auto-sklearn/master/requirements.txt | xargs -n 1 -L 1 pip install
```

I get this error

```
'xargs' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

How to fix that?

When I try the 2nd step

```
pip install auto-sklearn

ValueError: Detected unsupported operating system: win32. Please check the compability information of auto-sklearn: http://automl.github.io/auto-sklearn/stable/installation.html#windows-osx-compability
```

which i think it is due to the step 1 fail.

anyone can help me fixing this error?

Comment: Make sure you have anaconda 64-bit

Comment: The line containing 'xargs' is for installation on a linux machine. A bit further down the page: "Therefore, it is not possible to run auto-sklearn on a Windows machine." So the moral of the story is (like always) as soon as you try do something actually interesting windows fails miserably ...

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar it is Anaconda 64 bit

Comment: I found this link that may help in installing pyodbc on Ubuntu bash 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/python-sql-driver-pyodbc?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AutoSklearn is built for unix systems only. If you see first line in System requirement [here](https://automl.github.io/auto-sklearn/stable/installation.html), it is Linux operating system.

The reason is resource module is only available in linux system. Find details about it on https://automl.github.io/auto-sklearn/stable/installation.html#windows

Comment: So VM is the only way??

Comment: @asmgx VM is a possibility, yet it would be highly inefficient to run auto-sklearn on VM

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use the following:

1. Google Colab ([link](https://colab.research.google.com/))
2. Kaggle Notebook ([link](https://kaggle.com/))
3. Docker - Creating Python image in it! ([link](https://www.docker.com/products/docker-desktop/))